# Finding an unknown magnitude

Tags: vectors

This is going to sound very weird, but how do you find a magnitude with unknown vectors?
I'm currently stuck on a question that says "If vectors A and B are opposite vectors and the magnitude of A is 5, what is the magnitude of B?"
I'm only looking for a way to answer the question and it's probably very simple, I just don't have anything related to the question in my notes.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

The key word is **opposite** vector.

That is we have the relationship $B=-A$. Hence given $\|A\|$, we should be able to find $\|B\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(a,b,c)$ then $-A=(-a,-b,-c)$.

We know that $$\sqrt {a^2+b^2+c^2 }=5$$ what is $$\sqrt {(-a)^2+(-b)^2+(-c)^2 }=?$$